# how can I use functions as well as variables in the expression for ng-options in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 select boxes, one to choose the user type (e.g. groups or individual) and the 2nd to the out put of the 1st one to display the options to choose the user/group. 
is there anyway that in my expressions for `ng-options` I could pass it a function instead of a variable like so :

```
ng-options="user.id as user.description for user in getUserList(userType)"
```

where userType is the ng-model of the first select box

I'm under the impression from my own trials that this is not possible (seem's to crash the the current tab in chrome and the entire application in firefox).

what would be the best approach to this. I have a lot of selects that use this kind of 2 select box setup so it would be nice If I could avoid copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on your data, it could be as simple as:

```
<select ng-model="type" ng-options="type for type in types"></select>
<select ng-model="user" ng-options="user.name for user in users[type]" ng-if="type != 'skipped'"></select>
```

with:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.types = ['group', 'individual', 'skipped'];
  $scope.type = $scope.types[0];

  $scope.users = {
    group: [
      { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
      { id: 2, name: 'bar' }
    ],
    individual: [
      { id: 3, name: 'foobar' },
      { id: 4, name: 'barfoo' }
    ]
  };
}]);
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/EyuQ/2/

Comment: this is definitively the closest to achieveing what I was asking for, thank you, but just to throw a curve ball here, I have a 3rd case where the user type is "skipped", in this case I need to disable the select box with the only value is "skipped", I know I can just add the values in the `$scope.users` but whould you have any suggestions as to how to disable it in that case. ng-change maybe?

Comment: So you want to disabled the user selection (the 2nd select) in case the selected type is `skipped`?

Comment: personally, I would just add `ng-if="type != 'skipped'"` on the second select then (see the update). Or `ng-hide/show/disabled`, it deponds on your UI requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a function in ng-options try this;

In your first select box use `ng-change` directive like this;

```
<select ng-options="user.id as user.description for user in firstSelect" ng-model="firstSelectBox" ng-change="change();"></select>
```

In your controller;

```
$scope.firstSelect=[{values of first select box}]

$scope.change = function(){
$value = $scope.firstSelectBox;
$http.get('API url').success(function (data) {
$scope.secondSelect = data;
});
}
```

Change your second select box as;

```
<select ng-options="user.id as user.description for user in secondSelect" ng-model="secondSelectBox"></select>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as below:

> HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="BookingCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selected.Type" ng-options="s.Type for s in data">
        <option value="">-- Type --</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="selected.Books" ng-options="b.Books for b in selected.Type.Books">
        <option value="">-- Books --</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="selected.c" ng-options="f.c for f in selected.Type.cat">
        <option value="">-- Category --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

> JS

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'myApp', [] );

myApp.controller( 'BookingCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ( $scope, $location ) {

    $scope.selected = {};

    $scope.data = [
        {
            "id" : "0",
            "Type" : "Study",
            "Books" : [
                { "Books" : "Study Book 1" },
                { "Books" : "Study Book 2" },
                { "Books" : "Study Book 3" }
            ],
            "cat" : [
                { "c" : "#1" },
                { "c" : "#2" },
                { "c" : "#3" }
            ]
        },{
            "id" : "1",
            "Type" : "General",
            "Books" : [
                { "Books" : "Book14" },
                { "Books" : "Book15" },
                { "Books" : "Book16" }
            ],
            "cat" : [
                { "c" : "#4" },
                { "c" : "#5" },
                { "c" : "#6" }
            ]
        }
    ];
}]);
```

check out this fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/PXwrf/2/